# Free service that allows storing game data online?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, slicehost

I have created a small game in Java and I would like to add the ability for a player to publish his highscores online.

I'm willing to write the server software myself (it's easy these days with Ruby Mongrel, or even C++). I just need to have some sort hosting. One solution that immediately comes to mind is [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). But that's kind of expensive for my needs. Since the requirements are very minimal (I don't even need a website, just a web service) I think there may be a cheaper solution out there.

Does anyone know of a free or cheap provider for this kind of thing?

#### Update

For those interested, this is solution I came up with:

- a [SliceHost](http://www.slicehost.com/)
- purchased a domain name
- [C++ HTTP server](http://code.google.com/p/stacked-crooked/source/browse/#svn/trunk/PlayGroundCpp/HighScoreServer/src)

  - built upon the [Poco HTTPServer](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html)
  - uses SQLite database via [Poco Data](http://pocoproject.org/blog/?p=24)
- Server implements a REST API supporting

  - High Score table

    - [/hs](http://stacked-crooked.com/hs) content type deduced from accept header
    - [/hs.xml](http://stacked-crooked.com/hs.xml) forces xml
    - [/hs.txt](http://stacked-crooked.com/hs.txt) forces plain text
  - [/hs/add](http://stacked-crooked.com/hs/add) html form, does a POST using XMLHttpRequest
  - [/hof](http://stacked-crooked.com/hof) Hall of Fame, content type deduced from accept header

    - [/hof.txt](http://stacked-crooked.com/hof.txt) forces plain text
    - [/hof.xml](http://stacked-crooked.com/hof.xml) forces xml
- game: [my own Tetris clone](http://code.google.com/p/stacked-crooked/source/browse/trunk/PlayGround/Clojure/Tetris.clj) written in [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com) or any other small-scale VPS provider could probably work. You might even be able to write it as a small app and publish it on [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/), which is free up to a certain point.

Comment: Slicehost looks like a very attractive solution :)

Comment: Honestly if you think you can, GAE would probably be the best choice (given that it's free). The GAE framework is pretty simple to work with, especially for something like a basic high-score server that you seem to be going for, and you can use either Java or Python to make apps for it.

Comment: Thanks, but I really wanted to set something up from scratch in order to maximize the learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

google app engine comes to mind: http://code.google.com/appengine/